# How can I convert text into link using Jquery and assign a function using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

How can I convert text into link using jQuery and assign a function? I have a table and I want to convert table’s last row’s first cell text into link and assign onclick function “DisplayDetails()”.

My table name is “ScoreCardDataCurrentTable”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var cell = $('#ScoreCardDataCurrentTable tr:last td:first');

var text = $(cell).text();

var link = $('<a />').text(text).bind('click', function(){
    // your code here
    DisplayDetails();

});

$(cell).html(link);
```

// I'm assuming that your table has an ID of ScoreCardDataCurrentTable

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#ScoreCardDataCurrentTable").children("tr:last").children("td:first").click(function(){
   DisplayDetails()
});
```

This code will set call `DisplayDetails()` when the first cell of the last row in the table is clicked.  If you want the text itself to call the function you will have to tell us what the text is contained in.

it may be simpler just to use a link with an id and use CSS to style it how you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myCell = $('#mytable>tr:last>td:first');
var myContents = myCell.html();

//We do not use onclick attribute cause it may bring hell to our known world
var pseudoLink = $('<a>'+myContents+'</a>').click( function() {
  //Stuff here
});
```